# How to Split Up an Array of Times into Hours, Minutes, Seconds in Python?

Tags: python, time

I have a piece of code that reads in 141 files that have a time at the end of their name. For example the file names look like:

```
400km_t150317_054000
400km_t150317_054100
400km_t150317_054200
```

Below is the code that reads the 141 files and separates the filename to extract the time into hours, minutes, seconds.

```
filenames = [pathlib.Path(f).stem for f in os.listdir('Path')]

time_array = []
for f in filenames:
    parts = f.split('_')
    time_string = parts[-1]
    time_obj = time.strptime(time_string, '%H%M%S')
    time_array.append(time_obj)
```

For reference, the first few lines of the time_array output look like the following:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=5, tm_min=40, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1), 
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=5, tm_min=41, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1),
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=5, tm_min=42, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1), 
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=5, tm_min=43, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

There are 141 outputs like the ones above. What I want to do is extract the hour, minute, and second from each of the 141 outputs and create an array with just the hour, minute, second for the first output, then for the next output and so on. I want this because I then want to get the time in the form of decimal hours so hour + (minute/60) + (second/3600). I'm going to then be using that array of decimal hours in a for loop later on.

I know that the code below will work to extract the hour, minute, second from one output correctly, but I'm not sure how to write a code to do this for all 141 outputs. Below I am showing how it works for the first output that I have above.

```
t = time_array[0]
hour = t.tm_hour
minute = t.tm_min
second = t.tm_sec
```

```
print(hour, minute, second)
5 40 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuple to create an array with just the hour, minute, second.

```
arr = [(t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec) for t in time_array]
```

Answer (score 1):

`time_array_hms = [(t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec) for t in time_array]`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

All in one solution depending on how you want to proceed:

```py
from datetime import datetime

names = [
    '400km_t150317_054000',
    '400km_t150317_054100',
    '400km_t150317_054200'
] # replace with actual filenames

for name in names:
    # ignore prefix, just keep time-suffix
    _, time_str = name.split('_t')
    # extract just time - not datetime
    time = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H%M%S_%f').time()

    # if you need the time-object
    print(time)
    # to extract fields
    print(time.hour, time.minute, time.second)
    # representation as hour-decimals
    print(time.hour + time.minute/60 + time.second/3_600)
```

output:

```
15:03:17.054000
15 3 17
15.054722222222223
15:03:17.054100
15 3 17
15.054722222222223
15:03:17.054200
15 3 17
15.054722222222223
```